# Get data PostgreSQL TypeORM. Multiple Conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, backend, typeorm

I need to get data from my database with couple conditions: the match of two different strings that the backend will receive, but each one can be found at 2 different columns inside a row of the table.

Below is the code that i was trying but it only identifies one of the matches that i need, if the location is found the specialty is not filtered.

What is the better way to filter both cases?

```js
const result = await LawyersRepo.createQueryBuilder("lawyers")
    .where("lawyers.city = :city", {
      city: location,
    })
    .orWhere("lawyers.state = :state", {
      state: location,
    })
    .andWhere("lawyers.specialties like :specialties", {
      specialties: `${specialty}%`,
    })
    .orWhere("lawyers.occupation_area like :specialties", {
      specialties: `${specialty}%`,
    })
    .getMany();
```

Comment: can you explain what do you want exactly ?

Comment: of course! If I request, for example, the data { location: "Any City", specialty: "Random specialty that isn't in any row"} Instead of return no data the database return all data with the "location" field match..... i need both conditions working effectively...

Answer (score 0):

to explain how typeorm works it will get the rows matching all the where, andWhere
in your case it will find any row matching (city and speciality),

but the thing is it will get any thing matching the orWhere, and ignores any other condition so it will fetch any thing matching the state or the occupation_area,

so you have to devide your condition into brackets of orWhere like so:
(condition1 AND condition2) OrWhere (condition3 AND condition4)